WETH tokens burned after Single Swap
WETH is being sent to 0x000... address automatically after swapping: https://base.blockscout.com/address/0xD73356664dBbD21A9D6B66B3877a7e260D3Ee7f4?tab=token_transfers
I just checked balanceOf on WETH contract and that was also 0. So clearly I don't possess WETH.
I've been following the guide for doing Uniswap Single Swap: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/swaps/single-swaps
My use-case is taking arbitrary ERC20 token and converting that to ETH. My contract is straightforward:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

address constant SWAP_ROUTER_02 = 0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481;
address constant WETH = 0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006;
address constant DEGEN = 0x4ed4E862860beD51a9570b96d89aF5E1B0Efefed;

contract UniswapV3SingleHopSwap {
    ISwapRouter02 private constant router = ISwapRouter02(SWAP_ROUTER_02);
    IWETH private constant weth = IWETH(WETH);
    IERC20 private constant degen = IERC20(DEGEN);

    event Swap(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOut);

    function swapExactInputSingleHop(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin
    ) external {
        degen.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
        degen.approve(address(router), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter02.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter02
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: DEGEN,
                tokenOut: WETH,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: address(this),
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: amountOutMin,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        // router.exactInputSingle(params);
        uint256 amountOut = router.exactInputSingle(params);

        emit Swap(amountIn, amountOut);
    }

    function unwrapWETH(uint256 amount) external {
        weth.withdraw(amount);
    }

    function withdrawAll(uint256 amount) external {
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "ETH transfer failed");
    }

    // Allow contract to receive ETH
    receive() external payable {}
}


Previously I thought unwrapETH had an issue because it kept failing. But it seems like I have 0 WETH after the swap. I usually put amountOut as zero. But I've tried putting in a higher number as well.

My guess is that there is a bot that scans contracts that have no access controls and tries to exploit them. I was able to get around this by making my contract Ownable and changing the withdrawAll method to:
function withdrawAll(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
    require(success, "ETH transfer failed");
}

